# Why is some columns hiding in ngx-datatable?

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I try to do a ngx-datatable, but the last columns are hiding. Anybody know why?

```
<ngx-datatable #tableResponsive class="bootstrap core-bootstrap" [columnMode]="ColumnMode.force" [headerHeight]="50" [footerHeight]="50" [rowHeight]="50" [limit]="10" [rows]="rows" [scrollbarH]="true">
              <ngx-datatable-column name="Email" prop="email" >
              </ngx-datatable-column>
              <ngx-datatable-column name="Email" prop="email" >
              </ngx-datatable-column>
              <ngx-datatable-column name="Email" prop="email" >
              </ngx-datatable-column>
              <ngx-datatable-column name="Email" prop="email" >
              </ngx-datatable-column>
              <ngx-datatable-column name="Email" prop="email" >
              </ngx-datatable-column>
              <ngx-datatable-column name="Email" prop="email" >
              </ngx-datatable-column>
              <ngx-datatable-column name="Email" prop="email" >
              </ngx-datatable-column>
              <ngx-datatable-column name="Age" prop="age" >
              </ngx-datatable-column>
              <ngx-datatable-column name="Age" prop="age" >
              </ngx-datatable-column>
              <ngx-datatable-column name="Age" prop="age" >
              </ngx-datatable-column>
              <ngx-datatable-column name="Age" prop="age" >
              </ngx-datatable-column>
              <ngx-datatable-column name="Age" prop="age" >
              </ngx-datatable-column>
              <ngx-datatable-column name="Age1" prop="age" >
              </ngx-datatable-column>
</ngx-datatable>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you reproduce in stackblitz?

Comment: I think your issue is on CSS styles that need to be updated, Try to remove CSS classes `class="bootstrap core-bootstrap"` and check